# Condition in Elastic search query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search for:  When a customer id exists in venue >> blocked_for_customers Then I just want to remove tickets of ticket_type=2 from the search result. The ES query I posted is not working as expected. Can anyone help me to find out what am I doing wrong?

Here is my ES document:

```
{
  "took":44,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":
  {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":
  {
    "total":1,
    "max_score":1,
    "hits":
    [{
      "_index":"es_db",
      "_type":"event",
      "_id":"123",
      "_score":1,
      "_source":
      {
        "event_id":123,
        "name":"test event",
        "event_date":"2016-08-10T03:30:00",
        "status":1,
        "venue":
        [{
          "city":"dummy city",
          "name":"dummy name",
          "state":"dummy state",
          "venue_id":100,
          "blocked_for_customers":[1,2]
        }],
        "ticket_group":
        [{
          "ticket_type":1,
          "available":42,
          "price":100,
          "customer_id":1,
          "id":1
        },
        {
          "ticket_type":3,
          "available":5,
          "price":12.5,
          "id":2,
          "customer_id":1
        },
        {
          "ticket_type":2,
          "available":10,
          "id":3,
          "customer_id":1,
          "price":10
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Here is my ES query :

```
{
  "query":
  {
    "bool":
    {
      "must":
      [{
        "nested":
        {
          "path":"ticket_group",
          "score_mode":"max",
          "inner_hits":
          {
            "from":0,
            "size":10000
          },
          "query":
          {
            "bool":
            {
              "must":
              [{
                "bool":
                {
                  "minimum_should_match":1,
                  "should":
                  [{
                    "bool":
                    {
                      "must":
                      [{
                        "match":
                        {
                          "venue.blocked_for_customers":1
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms":
                        {
                          "ticket_group.ticket_type":[1,3]
                        }
                      }]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool":
                    {
                      "must":
                      [{
                        "bool":
                        {
                          "must_not":
                          [{
                            "match":
                            {
                              "venue.blocked_for_customers":1
                            }
                          }]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool":
                        {
                          "must":
                          [{
                            "terms":
                            {
                              "ticket_group.ticket_type":[1,3,2]
                            }
                          }]
                        }
                      }]
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match":
        {
          "status":1
        }
      }]
    } 
  },
  "size":10,
  "from":0,
  "sort":
  {
    "event_date":
    {
      "order":"asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings :

```
{"mappings": {
      "event":{
         "properties":{
            "event_date":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "event_id":{
               "type":"integer",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "name":{
               "type":"string",
               "analyzer":"autocomplete",
               "search_analyzer":"standard",
               "fields":{
                  "raw":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "status":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "ticket_group":{
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{
                  "price":{
                     "type":"double",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "ticket_type":{
                     "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "available":{
                     "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "customer_id":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "id":{
                     "type":"integer",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "venue":{
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{
                  "blocked_for_customers" :{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "analyzer":"autocomplete",
                     "search_analyzer":"standard"
                  },
                  "venue_id":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "city":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "state":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: provide the mapping for the document as well?

Comment: is it necessary  ?

Comment: if you want help, yes :-)

Comment: @Val, i have added mappings as well.

Comment: This query is quite hard to read, are you make each of those conditions to work separately? One thing that comes to my mind is that you can't really "remove" tickets from your search result because elastic returns the document as a whole - in your case, the event.